# Linq to sql add/dynamic OR WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

There are main query

**SELECT item FROM QuickRecords WHERE (CategoryId = @CategoryId AND CategoryUserId = @UserId)**

```cs
            var q = from items in db.QuickRecords
               where items.CategoryId == category && items.CategoryUserId == UserId
               select items;
```

There are dynamic filter, sample "22,333"

```cs
            string[] filters = filter.Split(',');
            foreach (string item in filters)
            {
                string f = "%" + item.ToLower() + "%";
                q = q.Where(x => x.Record.Contains(f));
            }
```

How add to sql query

**AND (Record LIKE '%22%' OR Record LIKE '%333%')**

Comment: You should change this to use [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] filters = filter.Split(',');
var q = from items in db.QuickRecords
               where items.CategoryId == category && items.CategoryUserId == UserId
                      && filters.Any(f=> item.Record.Contains(f))
               select items;
```

Comment: Will the query provider be able to translate that query as expected?